# При десериализации класса программа не видит класс этого объект java

Tags: java, javafx, исключения

У меня есть сервер и клиент. Клиент посылает запрос к серверу , а тот в свою очередь делает запрос к бд и получает ResultSet. После чего формирует список объектов с помощью ResultSet и сериализует из в буфер потом в сокет. Клиент же в свою очередь должен получить эту инфу и десериализовать лист объектов. Я получал ошибку ClassNotFoundException. Потом я начал передавать не список а один объект.Проблема не ушла. И на сервер и на клиенте есть класс который сериализуется они полностью идентичны.

Вот класс:

```
package main;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Messag implements Serializable {
    String login;
    String time;
    String message;
    Messag(String login,String time,String message){
        this.login = login;
        this.time = time;
        this.message = message;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return login + "/" + time + "/" + message;
    }
}
```

Сервер:

```
while (resSet.next()){
                    Messag message = new Messag(resSet.getString(1),resSet.getString(2),resSet.getString(3));
                    listMessage.add(message);
                }
                /*
                for (Message message : listMessage) {
                    System.out.println(message.toString());

                }
                */
                Messag msg = listMessage.get(1);
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baosSerializable);
                oos.writeObject(msg);

                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(baosSerializable.toByteArray());
                System.out.println(baosSerializable.toByteArray().length + " Длина буфера");
                while (buffer.hasRemaining())
                    sc.write(buffer);
```

Длина выводится на сервере и на клиенте что бы убедиться что все доходит(И все доходит =) )
Клиент:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             for ( int cnt; (cnt = clientSocket.read(buf.clear())) != -1; )
                 baos.write(buf.array(),0, cnt);
             System.out.println(baos.toByteArray().length + " Длина буфера");
             ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
             ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);

             ois.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("Messag");
             Messag msg = (Messag)ois.readObject();
```

Ошибка выводится тут:
                 ois.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("Messag");
и ошибка NullPointerException. Если эту строку убрать то будет ошибка на след строке ClassNotFoundException ((

Answer (score 0):

У Вас, видимо, в classpath клиента нет вашего класса `main.Messag`. 
Добавьте ваш класс в classpath клиента и уберите `ois.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("Messag");` - если класс уже будет в classpath - это вызов не нужен. К тому же, имя класса указано не верно - должно быть `loadClass("main.Messag")`

Comment: Может быть еще имеет смысл явно добавить скрытый идентификатор класса, они могут различаться в обоих местах. Кажется поле зовут `SerialVersionUID`